# Keep indefinite connections open on TCP server with asyncio streams?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I'm trying to understand how to use asyncio streams for multiple connections that will keep sending messages until a predefined condition  or a socket timeout. Looking at Python docs, they provide the following example for a TCP server based on asyncio streams:

```
import asyncio

async def handle_echo(reader, writer):
    data = await reader.read(100)
    message = data.decode()
    addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')

    print(f"Received {message!r} from {addr!r}")

    print(f"Send: {message!r}")
    writer.write(data)
    await writer.drain()

    print("Close the connection")
    writer.close()

async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(
        handle_echo, '127.0.0.1', 8888)

    addrs = ', '.join(str(sock.getsockname()) for sock in server.sockets)
    print(f'Serving on {addrs}')

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()

asyncio.run(main())
```

What I'm trying to do is more complex and it looks more like so (a lot of it is pseudocode, written in capital letters or with implementation omitted):

```
import asyncio

async def io_control(queue):
   while true:
      ...
# do I/O control in this function ... 

async def data_processing(queue):
   while true:
      ...
# perform data handling

async def handle_data(reader, writer):
    data = await reader.read()
    message = data.decode()
    addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')

    print(f"Received {message!r} from {addr!r}")
    
    #do stuff with a queue - pass messages to other two async functions as needed        

    #keep open until something happens
    if(ERROR or SOCKET_TIMEOUT):
       writer.close()

async def server(queue):
    server = await asyncio.start_server(
        handle_data, '127.0.0.1', 8888)

    addrs = ', '.join(str(sock.getsockname()) for sock in server.sockets)
    print(f'Serving on {addrs}')

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()

async def main():

    queue_io = asyncio.Queue()
    queue_data = asyncio.Queue()
    
    asyncio.run(server(queue_data))
    asyncio.run(data_handling(queue_data))
    asyncio.run(io_control(queue_io))

asyncio.run(main())
```

Does this look feasible? I'm not used to working with co-routines (I'm coming from more of a multi-threading paradigm), so I'm not sure if what I'm doing is right or if I have to explicitly include yields or do any extra stuff.

Comment: TCP involves a fair amount of overhead. If your remote devices are sending messages continuously, would UDP be a better choice?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular that was considered when we decided that we'll make our own remote devices rather than use off-the shelf hardware; it wouldn't be hard to switch to it on the client side. Low-level wise it would mean I'd just be able to keep a socket open on a specific address+port and read incoming messages from all of the devices that are sending messages to the server--but how would the code change in the above case? Would I have to use socket module directly?

Comment: Sorry, Python is not my thing. I'm just comparing what you're proposing with what my employer does, and UDP was considered a better choice. I didn't write the server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just need the TCP server to be able to handle multiple concurrent connections. The [`start_server`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.start_server) function should already give you everything you need.

The first parameter `client_connected_cb` is a coroutine function called whenever a client establishes a connection. If you introduce a loop into that function (in your example code `handle_data`), you can keep the connection open until some criterion is met. What conditions *exactly* should lead to closing the connection is up to you, and the implementation details will obviously depend on that. The simplest approach I can imagine is something like this:

```py
import asyncio
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

async def handle_data(reader, writer):
    while True:
        data = (await reader.readline()).decode().strip()
        if not data:
            log.debug("client disconnected")
            break
        response = await your_data_processing_function(data)
        writer.write(response.encode())
        await writer.drain()

...

async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(handle_data, '127.0.0.1', 8888)
    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

There is *theoretically* no limit for the number of concurrent connections.

If your `client_connected_cb` is a coroutine function, each new connection will schedule a new [task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task) for the event loop. That is where the concurrency comes from. The magic then happens at the point of `await`ing new data from the client; that is where the event loop can switch execution to another coroutine. All this happens behind the scenes, so to speak.

If you want to introduce a timeout, you could wrap the awaitable `readline` coroutine in a [`wait_for`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for) for example and then catch the [`TimeoutError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-exceptions.html#asyncio.TimeoutError) exiting the loop.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's awesome, I'll have to try it out first, but just to clarify my understanding, since the callback is defined as a coroutine (async def), each time it's called a task is created, correct, as you've stated. If I had defined the callback without "def async", then it'd call the same function with the same client each time, right?

Comment: @NickS. To be honest, I have never tested the server's behavior with a non-`async` function as callback. But I am pretty sure that you don't get any concurrency that way, since a regular function would just block the event loop until it returns. No `await` means no context switch, means the event loop is stuck executing that one client callback. It doesn't really make sense to use it this way, in my opinion.

Comment: This was just a roundabout way of asking how the task is created without explicitly calling "create_task", but I see where it says so in the docs now. I guess if I want to know more, I can take a look at the source code. Thanks!